# Replacing items in a list the traditional way

Tags: python

Trying to replace items in a list the traditional way.

```
lst = [1,2,3]
for i in lst:
    i = 50

print (lst)

wanted outcome: [50,50,50]
```

Could someone explain why this doesnt work as well? Thank you

obv, this doenst work, but i was wondering if there was a method to solve this with very similar structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
lst = [1,2,3]
for i in range(len(lst)):
    lst[i] = 50

print (lst)
```

When you do `for x in lst`, you create an unbound variable. Changing its value won't affect the list.

So you need to modify the list at the given index.

Comment: is this outcome possible to achieve without using index or enumerate?

Comment: To modify a value within a list, you must modify the value at the corresponding index at some point.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the 'unbound variable' part? do you mean the 'item' in the for loops is only accessible in that for loop and that for loop only?

Comment: Bop. If you call a print(i) (with respect to your first code) out of the loop, the last list element should be displayed. I mean than 'for elem in lst' is equal to make an independant copy of 'lst[i]'. So modifying elem won't affect lst[i]

Comment: no problem! If the answer was helpful, you can think about accepting it :) (click on the gray tick top left of it)

Comment: can another explanation be as follows? the id of the i in 'for i in lst' is different from the id of the i in the next line? thats why its not mutating the list

Comment: Well, first i is for index. In your post you call a list element i. Bad idea. A list element can be 'elem' at index i. There is no id, there is the index. for elem in lst does not tell you the index. For i, elem in enumerate(lst) does tell you the index and the element at this index in the list. For i in range(len(lst)) gives you the index which you can use in lst[i] to get the element at this index!

Answer (score 1):

```
ls = [1, 2, 3]

ls = [50 for _ in ls]

for i, ele in enumerate(ls):
    ls[i] = 50

ls = [50] * len(ls)
```

Here is a few ways. I suppose you are looking for the [enumerate](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/enumerate) example

Comment: Enumerate is not the traditional way ;)

Comment: @Synthase Enumerate has been in Python for 7 years so I would consider is traditional to Python although I see your point.

Comment: Yes traditional to Python, I agree!